# Cheerio cannot find table by id

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I'm trying to scrape https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/p/pujolal01.shtml for player stats, specifically getting from the Standard Batting and Player Value--Batting tables. Here's part of my code:

```
const page = cheerio.load(response.data);
const statsTable = page('#batting_standard');
const rows = statsTable.find('tbody > tr').not('.minors_table').add(statsTable.find('tfoot > tr:first'));
const moreStatsTable = page('#batting_value');
const moreRows = moreStatsTable.find('tbody > tr, tfoot > tr:first');
```

For some reason, it's able to retrieve the first table (id = 'batting_standard'), but not the second (id = 'batting_value'), such that `moreStatsTable = null`. What's going on? I don't understand why cheerio can't find the value table, since it has a unique id. Is it just me having this issue?

Comment: I don't know cheerio, but I do know those reference.com sites. If you look at the html source, you'll notice that 1 (or a few tables) are present as you normally would see. However, the other tables in the html are within the comments. you'll need to pull out the tables within the comments to parse those tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on [chitown88's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68279497/cheerio-cannot-find-table-by-id#comment120706175_68279497), the data you want appears to be inside comments. The site uses JS after the page loads to display the HTML from these comments.

There's a useful [Cheerio GitHub issue #423](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/issues/423#issuecomment-508722958) which has a method of identifying and extracting data from comments. I adapted this to your use case to find the particular table you want:

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // 1.0.0-rc.12

const url = "https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/p/pujolal01.shtml";

fetch(url) // Node 18 or install node-fetch, or use another library like axios
  .then(res => {
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw Error(res.statusText);
    }

    return res.text();
  })
  .then(html => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);

    $("*").map((i, el) => {
      $(el).contents().map((i, el) => {
        if (el.type === "comment") {
          const $ = cheerio.load(el.data);
          const table = $("#batting_value").first();

          if (table.length) {
            const data = [...table.find("tr")].map(e =>
              [...$(e).find("td, th")].map(e => $(e).text().trim())
            );
            // trim the table a bit for display
            console.table(data.slice(0, 4).map(e => e.slice(0, 4)));
          }
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

Output:

```
┌─────────┬────────┬───────┬───────┬──────┐
│ (index) │   0    │   1   │   2   │  3   │
├─────────┼────────┼───────┼───────┼──────┤
│    0    │ 'Year' │ 'Age' │ 'Tm'  │ 'Lg' │
│    1    │ '2001' │ '21'  │ 'STL' │ 'NL' │
│    2    │ '2002' │ '22'  │ 'STL' │ 'NL' │
│    3    │ '2003' │ '23'  │ 'STL' │ 'NL' │
└─────────┴────────┴───────┴───────┴──────┘
```